# How to display image in WinForms and then delete?

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms

When my form opens it uses the file path that is provided from another form and displays the images, and when I close the form I want it to delete all the images.

But when I close it keeps stating the file is being used, is there a better way of doing it please?

```
public frmMark(string strImagePath)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pbImage1.Image = new Bitmap(strImagePath + "1.jpg");
    pbImage2.Image = new Bitmap(strImagePath + "2.jpg");
    pbImage3.Image = new Bitmap(strImagePath + "3.jpg");
}

private void frmMark_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    File.Delete(deletepath + "1.jpg");
}
```

Comment: try the event closed and not closing

Comment: @burnsi - you are clearly wrong about the placement of the opening `{` of the method :D

Comment: `pbImage1.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(strImagePath, "1.jpg")), true));`....etc. to avoid locking the file.

Comment: @RandRandom, I'm not sure that that would be enough still because the `Bitmap` objects are still not being disposed explicitly and I don't know that they would be implicitly either. Haven't tested to find out though.

Comment: @dr.null, no need to do that since they added the `Imagelocation` property and the `Load` method, unless you need to `Image` object for some purpose other than displaying in the `PictureBox`.

Comment: @user18387401 Good point Mr. J

Answer (score 5):

Change this:

```cs
pbImage1.Image = new Bitmap(strImagePath + "1.jpg");
```

to this:

```cs
pbImage1.ImageLocation = Path.Combine(strImagePath, "1.jpg");
```

and for the others and your issue should go away because the files will not be locked, so you don't have to worry about unlocking them.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create a language extension which clones the original image, load the image then deletes the physical file.

```
public static class PictureBoxExtensions
{
    public static void LoadClone(this PictureBox pictureBox, string fileName)
    {
        var imageOriginal = Image.FromFile(fileName);

        var imageClone = new Bitmap(imageOriginal.Width, imageOriginal.Height);

        Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(imageClone);
        gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;
        gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        gr.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed;
        gr.DrawImage(imageOriginal, 0, 0, imageOriginal.Width, imageOriginal.Height);
        gr.Dispose();
        imageOriginal.Dispose();

        pictureBox.Image = imageClone; // assign the clone to picture box
        File.Delete(fileName); // remove original
    }
}
```

Or if not always needing to remove an image add another parameter,in this case remove where the default is to remove which of course you can set the default to false.

```
public static class PictureBoxExtensions
{
    public static void LoadClone(this PictureBox pictureBox, string fileName, bool remove = true)
    {
        var imageOriginal = Image.FromFile(fileName);

        var imageClone = new Bitmap(imageOriginal.Width, imageOriginal.Height);

        Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(imageClone);
        gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;
        gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        gr.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed;
        gr.DrawImage(imageOriginal, 0, 0, imageOriginal.Width, imageOriginal.Height);
        gr.Dispose();
        imageOriginal.Dispose();

        pictureBox.Image = imageClone; // assign the clone to picture box

        if (remove)
        {
            File.Delete(fileName); // remove original
        }
        
    }
}
```

Usage

```
public frmMark(string strImagePath)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pbImage1.LoadClone(strImagePath + "1.jpg");
    pbImage2.LoadClone(strImagePath + "2.jpg");
    pbImage2.LoadClone(strImagePath + "3.jpg");
}
```